# handling when a button is pressed

Tags: c, button, avr, atmega

I have the current code, and ive tried to add in a toggle_speed() function, this will be called in the main function in an if statement of, `else if (button_pushed() == 2)`. What im trying to accomplished is that when the button is pressed it doubles the speed, but if it is pushed again the speed will go back to normal. This is the code I have, all help is appreciated, im quite new to this. We are programming this onto AVR working with ATmega324A. Basically, I need help in constructing a valid toggle_speed function as what ive done is most certai

Comment: Well, first of all your speed variables are local variables - if you want to have these variables available in the code outside the interrupt handler, you need to store them somehow - for example via (static or global) volatile variables.

Comment: @Hulk ok cool, thanks for your help

Comment: Secondly, I find it strange that the `toggle_speed()`-function considers the `button_state` - in a function with that name, I'd only expect code to "toggle the speed", i.e. a function that toggles some boolean flag and possibly also changing the speed values, but certainly not taking inputs into account.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want something like this:

```
volatile uint32_t background_speed, alien_speed, projectile_speed;
...

void toggle_speed(void){
  static int doublespeedactive;
  doublespeedactive = !doublespeedactive;

  if (doublespeedactive)
  {
    background_speed = 600;
    alien_speed =  400;
    projectile_speed = 300;
  }
  else
  {
    background_speed = 600 / 2;
    alien_speed =  400 / 2;
    projectile_speed = 300 / 2;
  }
}
```

`doublespeedactive` is a state variable. If it's 1, then double speed is active, if it's 0, then normal speed is active.

`doublespeedactive = !doublespeedactive;` toggles the value of `doublespeedactive` from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1.

Read about the `!` operator.

However you don't call `toggle_speed` anywhere in the code you show in your question, so this answer is possibly incomplete.

Be aware that the `volatile` keyword is necessary if you intend to call `toogle_speed` from an ISR.

Comment: there is a h file to go with this c file that is included in the main c file where the toggle speed function is being called

Comment: im a little confused with doublespeedactive variable

Comment: @Mgert33 `doublespeedactive` is a state variable. If it's 1, then double speed is active, if it's 0, then normal speed is active. `doublespeedactive = !doublespeedactive;` toggles the value of `doublespeedactive` from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1. Read about the `!` operator.